# Ошибка C# после if аргумента

Tags: c#, if, while

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        farmer = new Farmer(1, 400);
    }
    else
    {
        farmer = new Farmer(1, 300);
    }
}
```

помогите
что я делаю не так
ошибка после   (checked)

cкрины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо должно быть `if (checkBox1.Checked)`  ибо checked ни к чему не относится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский cяб теперь пашет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский плюс checked является ключевым словом языка и в любом случае не может использоваться в качестве имени переменной/поля. Напишите ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreycha то, что ключевое даже по подсветке видно. Не стал писать поэтому.. Право ответа уступаю вам))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это скорее было дополнение для автора вопроса. Не ленитесь :).

Comment: использование тернарного оператора, вместо if `farmer = new Farmer(1, ((CheckBox)sender).Checked ? 400 : 300);`

Comment: Вставьте код вопроса в тело в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку [edit], расположенную под метками вопроса.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky иногда фото тоже нужно. в данном случае из фото даже лучше видно, имхо. Т.е. лучше кодом, конечно, но если есть фото, то, возможно, его вместе с кодом тоже можно приложить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDE говорит, что ошибка по двум причинам:

1. `checked` - ключевое слово, которое используется для явного включения проверки переполнения при выполнении арифметических операций и преобразований с данными целого типа. [см. документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/74b4xzyw.aspx). Поэтому использовать в `if` его уже нельзя и будет ошибка.
2. у `Checkbox` есть свойство [Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx). Замечу, что свойство пишется с заглавной буквы.

   Именно его надо проверять. Естественно надо указать в начале объект, а потом через точку свойство объекта. У вас сейчас оно если бы не было ключевым словом, то ни к чему не относится. А надо писать хотя бы `checkBox1.Checked`

   Т.к. свойство меняет именно этот объект? то можно скастовать объект, который послал событие и у него проверить `Checked`, т.е.

   ```
   if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked) { ...
   ```